# Split csv file by the value of a column - Apache Nifi

Tags: apache, csv, apache-nifi

I have a csv files, that it has the following structure.

```
ERP,J,JACKSON,8388 SOUTH CALIFORNIA ST.,TUCSON,AZ,85708,267-3352,,ALLENTON,MI,48002,810,710-0470,369-98-6555,462-11-4610,1953-05-00,F,
MARKETING,J,JACKSON,8388 SOUTH CALIFORNIA ST.,TUCSON,AZ,85708,267-3352,,ALLENTON,MI,48002,810,710-0470,369-98-6555,462-11-4610,1953-05-00,F,
```

As you can see there is not header, but for your information the first part (first column) represents the sector where are getting the data.

What I have to do is depending on the first column value, for example (MARKETING or ERP) I have to send all that rows to a different output directory.

For example, all rows with ERP to /output/ERP/
             all rows with MARKETING to /output/marketing/

I have an idea about how to do it, but my problem is about the RouteOnAttribute processor I am using, I don't know how to refer to the first column and to indicate what is the value (ERP or MARKETING) to later on send it to the correct output directory.

Here is my schema.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use ***`PartitionRecord`*** processor for this case.

Configure the processor with `record reader/writer controller services`. Even though if you are not having header you can use col1,col2...etc in avro schema.

- add new property that defines processor to use that field for partition the flowfile.

Now partition record processor adds the `partition field attribute` with value, by making use of this attribute value we can `dynamically store files` into respected directories dynamically.

***Flow:***

```
1.GetFile
2.PartitionRecord
3.PutFile //configure directory as /output/${<keep_partition_field_name_here>}
```

Please refer [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/191760/create-dynamic-partitions-based-on-flowfile-conten.html) link for configuring usage of partition record processor.

**(or)**

***Old Approach:***

Using **`RouteText`** processor instead of `SplitText + RouteOnAttribute` Processors

Configure RouteText processor as

[image]

Use the `ERP/MARKETING` connections connect to PutFile processor and use `RouteText.Route` attribute value to dynamically save the files into Directories.

**Flow:**

```
1.GetFile
2.RouteText
3.PutFile //configure directory as /output/${RouteText.Route}/
```

You can also use **Group Regular expression** property value to create partitions.

**Note**

Using **PartitionRecord processor will be more efficient** than RouteText processor.